# How to use javascript for sending remote notifications with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is an issue I am having with `Firebase` and push notifications.

In a web app, I want a button which sends a remote notification when clicked. This notification is meant to be received by an iOS app working together with my web-app.

The present question is about how to make this work. The web offers some example of how to receive notifications in a web application, but I did not find much about sending one, and this is precisely what I need to do.

Below is the relevant code, the problem is to know how to write the code for the *SendNotific()* function, and maybe some other details. I hope someone, expert on the subject will be able to provide me with some advice.

```
<body>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase.
  var config = {
    apiKey: "myyKeyyy",
    authDomain: "......firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://......firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "....",
    storageBucket: "........appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "........."
  },
  app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
  db = firebase.firestore(app);
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();

function SendNotific() {
// Code to send a notification.
........
}
</script>

<input type='button' id='PushNotif' style='font-size:20px' value='Send notification!' onClick='SendNotific()'>
</body>
```

Comment: You can't send a message from a web client without also setting up your own server infrastructure to actually send the message.  The web client will have to instruct the server to send the message.

Comment: I kind of expected that. And I can actually send a notification from the Firebase console indeed. But how do I make my web client instruct the server to send the message, as you suggest?

Comment: You should have a POST endpoint of the server which you can just trigger to let server know to handle the notification sending on your behalf and also you can instruct the server about the actual notification you want it to send in your POST request body

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send notifications using client, for sending notifications firebase has an [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) which should be used by the application server. Though if you are up to building a serverless app then you should consider [Firebase Cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) which you can trigger using a HTTP endpoint and the cloud function can handle the notifications sending job.

Comment: That seems the way to go indeed. I'll have see how to write a cloud function on Firebase then.

Comment: Yeah cloud functions are fun ! Also If this answer served your purpose then you should upvote it or accept it so it might help others as well ;)

Comment: I did start to follow that direction and made some progress. Unfortunately it does not quite work yet. I made another post about it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53552341/how-to-send-a-notification-with-firebase-cloud-function).